# How to get the postID inside 'content_save_pre'? Other hook?

Tags: posts, filters, hooks

I need to get the current PostID. I think in the function the postID is not existing yet. (Because save pre ...)

```
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'getImageUrlOutOfContent', 10, 1);
```

Am I right? How I can get the postID? Is there a better hook?
I am updating the content (text) and uploading and adding a postImage.

Thank you

Comment: If it's a new post and you are looking to update the content before it's saved then it will not have a $post->ID yet.  You'd need to allow the new post to be inserted into the DB, then get the resulting ID.

Comment: ok - is there a hook list? Sorry I could't find one using google.... So in this case I set the postimage after saving ...?!

Answer (score 0):

There's no hook for "give me a post ID before the post has been created".  You only get an ID after the post has been saved.  So yes, use the hook `'content_save_pre'` to modify your content before saving, then once you get back a post ID use that ID to update the post featured image.

There's a great answer describing how to acquire and set the image for a post, [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/how-do-i-set-a-featured-image-thumbnail-by-image-url-when-using-wp-insert-post)

And, the hook you'd use to trigger that set image routine would be `'save_post'` which is documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)